# Some functions in Pykov (Markov Chain) return 'umfpack' error

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to print a probability transition matrix using the module pykov.

My code is simple, following some of the examples in the tutorial:

```
import pykov
T = pykov.Chain({('A','B'): .3, ('A','A'): .7, ('B','A'): 1.})
T.fundamental_matrix()
```

The probabilities are calculated w/o problems, but this (and a few other functions), return the following error:

```
 1060             b[-1] = 1.
   1061             try:
-> 1062                 LU = pysparse.umfpack.factorize(M)
   1063             except SystemError:  #not elegant this singular matrix error..
   1064                 # really dirty trick ??

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'umfpack'
```

Can anybody help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to pysparse, but I was not able to replicate the error:

```
>>> import pykov
>>> T = pykov.Chain({('A','B'): .3, ('A','A'): .7, ('B','A'): 1.})
>>> T.fundamental_matrix()
{('B', 'A'): 0.17751479289940836, ('A', 'B'): 0.053254437869822445, ('A', 'A'):     0.94674556213017746, ('B', 'B'): 0.8224852071005917}
```

I am working with pysparse 1.1.1

```
>>> import pysparse
>>> pysparse.__version__
'1.1.1'
```

Comment: thank you for your help. I am using pysparse '1.2-dev'

Comment: The latest pykov version support Python3 and depends only on numpy and scipy.